# How to convert Hex value to its corresponding character

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently iam working on a mobile application using backbone framework. In it i'am taking a model into the html and passing it back to another view. Recently i noticed that special characters in the model are passed into another view as Hex value. For e.g. instead of " ' " backbone passed the value as " %19 ", for "space" it passes the value as " %A0 ". Right now i'am managing it by replace,

```
var sampleText;
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/%A0/g,'');
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/%19/g,'');
```

What happens if there are other special characters? Is there a way i can find the hex values in a sentence say :- 
"hello, Sampl'e text¡ "

I searched the google and i know how to convert Hex to ASCII, hex to normal character etc..

Has anyone come across these kind of problem, then how did you manage it?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: More explicitly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent